# Displaying images in NextJS crashes

Tags: arrays, image, next.js

I want to display images in next js, but it crashes each time and displays errors:

> DataCloneError: Data cannot be cloned, out of memory

Here is the full error on my console:

```
node:internal/event_target:641
  process.nextTick(() => { throw err; });
                           ^

DataCloneError: Data cannot be cloned, out of memory.
    at reportSuccess (C:\Users\RUTH'S PC\Desktop\perfect-market\node_modules\jest-worker\build\workers\threadChild.js:77:32)
Emitted 'error' event on Worker instance at:
    at Worker.[kOnErrorMessage] (node:internal/worker:296:10)
    at Worker.[kOnMessage] (node:internal/worker:307:37)
    at MessagePort.<anonymous> (node:internal/worker:210:57)
    at MessagePort.[nodejs.internal.kHybridDispatch] (node:internal/event_target:461:20)
    at MessagePort.exports.emitMessage (node:internal/per_context/messageport:23:28)
```

And here is my code that is made to display images:

```
const Slideshow = () => {
  return (
    <>
      {imageData.map((data) => (
        <div className="slide" key={data.id}>
          <Image
            className="image"
            src={data.image}
            width={500}
            height={500}
            quality="30"
          />
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: May not be related but how many images are you trying to render?

Comment: 5 but on a lazy loading

Comment: That shouldn't be an issue then. Are you certain that's the piece of code responsible for the OOM error?

Comment: I have a video loop at background, can it be the cause?